# Docker failed to pull image no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-layer

I'm creating a docker image from another image using the most simple docker file:

```
FROM <source image>
```

The image builds and tags successfully. However when I push it to an Azure Container Registry and pull the image I get the following error:

```
Failed to pull image "<tagged image name>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "<tagged image name>": failed to extract layer sha256:<layer id>: link /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/2700/fs/Files/Program Files/common files/Microsoft Shared/Ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/2700/fs/Files/Program Files (x86)/common files/Microsoft Shared/ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui: no such file or directory: unknown
```

The original image from the same registry pulls and runs successfully.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the code you use to build and tag the container? image names must be fully qualified

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same issue since I ran Windows container on Linux node. Please make sure your Windows container is running on Windows node.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Container Registry is a private registry. Hence, make sure you login to the registry before pulling the image.
Refer the link to know ways to authenticate
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this isn't an authentication issue. I can pull the original image from the same repo fine.

Comment: Where is this new image being built? Is this "other image" in Azure Registry?